# Triggering a logout and redirect using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

Fortunately, I know the script works.  The problems comes about that `$('input[value="Log Out"]').click();` Logout is too slow and gets overridden by the window redirect.  How can I add an additional time out or what would the community suggest to make this process less volatile?

```
unsafeWindow.likeMe = likeMe;
function likeMe() 
    {   


        input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(i = 0; i < input.length; i++) 
            {
                myID = input[i].getAttribute("data-profileid");
                if(myID != null && myID.indexOf("342584172457437") >= 0)
                input[i].click();

            }   
            setTimeout(function() {

            $('input[value="Log Out"]').click();
                window.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Nobody-and-everybody/342584172457437";// is there a way to add a check to see if logout was completed? if not, how would I add just another setTimeout();?

            }, 5000);

    }


$(window).load(function(){

    var isCtrl = false;
    document.onkeyup=function(e) {
        if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=false;
    }
    document.onkeydown=function(e){
        if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=true;
        if(e.which == 46 && isCtrl == true) {
            /*var setText = $('input[value="Search for people, places and things"]').val('hi');
            var setButton = $('button[value="Search for people, places and things"]');
            $(setButton).click();*/
            likeMe()

            return false;
        }

    }
```

---

*Creating a project using arduino, processing, javascript/jquery, greasemonkey and facebook.
Art installation.*

Comment: you should only redirect once the logout event is finished, not starting both at the same time

Comment: Yeah I figured this much; the problem is that setTimeout is the last line of code in the sequence.  Would you have any insight on how to add another 5 second time out or how to test when the logout is completed?

Comment: Can't help you, there's nothing related to log out process in your code

Comment: When you log out normally, doesn't a new page load?  (It does for me on Facebook -- as the target page seems to be.)  If so, then the redirect won't work if you wait.  Post an image of the logged-out page and whether it's AJAX'd in or a normal page load.

Comment: it does logout if you remove the redirect. and it does redirect if you remove the logout.  if you have both tho logout gets overridden by redirect because I believe theres not enough time inbetween the logout.

Comment: Yes but doesn't the log-out load a whole new page?  Or is just a bit of text changed by AJAX?  If it's Facebook, it's normally the former and your approach will not work (but GM can do it).  Link to the target page.

Comment: I removed the redirect heres an image of the logout http://vvcap.net/db/PqUIfDSpCZ9hQIxbLuNA.htp  what do you need a picture of next? I am using GM also

Comment: I was just trying to verify that logout behaved normally (which means that approach won't work).  From the picture, it looks like it does, but it would be nice to have confirmation.  The target page link helps with that and also lets us double check our code. ...  I'll have an answer in a bit, if somebody doesn't beat me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the logout loads a new page, so that if you wait for it, the redirect will never fire (because the page -- that the code was running in -- is gone)<sup>1</sup>.

So, that means that the script has to track login and desired-redirect state between pages.  One way to do that is with [GM_setValue()](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue).

To illustrate, here is a complete script that shows how to logout and then redirect.
In this case, it adds a button to the top-right corner of Facebook pages.  When pressed, the button (1) Logs you out, (2) Waits for the logout to finish, (3) Redirects to a new page.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name      _Logout and Redirect
// @include   http://www.facebook.com/*
// @require   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

//--- Are we on a log-in page and has a redirect been requested?
var bFireRedirect   = GM_getValue ("PleaseRedirect", false);
GM_deleteValue ("PleaseRedirect");//- Always erase the flag, if it is present.

if (bFireRedirect  &&  $("#login_form #loginbutton").length) {
    //--- We've just come from our auto-logout.  Redirect.
    window.location = "http://dogs.icanhascheezburger.com/"
}


//--- We only get this far if no redirect occurred.
$("body").append (
    '<button id="gmLogOutAndRedirectBtn">Logout and redirect</button>'
);

$("#gmLogOutAndRedirectBtn").click ( function () {
    GM_setValue ("PleaseRedirect", true);

    $('input[value="Log Out"]').click ();
} );

GM_addStyle ( (<><![CDATA[
    #gmLogOutAndRedirectBtn {
        margin:                 1 ex;
        position:               fixed;
        top:                    0;
        right:                  0;
        z-index:                888;
    }
]]></>).toString () );
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Newfangled pages -- where the logout triggers just a partial AJAX content change -- don't have this problem.  But as that is not the case here, it is for another time/question.

Comment: do you think they did this for security issues? how do you kno when it's just a partial page update?  because of the URL extension?  btw this worked amazingly thank you so much for your support brock!  Also, why do you know this? lol

Comment: No security issues, that's actually the oldest and simplest-to-program method.  The AJAX approach is still well in the minority.  You can tell if it's whole-page versus AJAX by monitoring the NET requests and also seeing if the Browser's [page/tab "throbber"](http://img249.imageshack.us/img249/5420/001busytab.jpg) starts whirling (it normally doesn't for AJAX).